# Values in a sub JSON array to an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdictionary

From a web service, I get a JSON response which looks like this.

```
{
    data =     {
        category = "Barclays Premier Leaguejk";
        "download_counter" = 1;
        id = 2;
        rating = 5;
        tags =         (
            "Primera A",
            "Primeira Liga"
        );
        title = "Carles Puyol";
    };
    status = 1;
}
```

Using `[data valueForKeyPath:@"tags"]`, I have taken out the sub array.

```
(
    "Primera A",
    "Primeira Liga"
)
```

I need to get the values inside into an `NSString`. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: the whole array as string? Like Json sring?

Comment: or do u want them to be joined in a string?

Comment: `componentsJoinedByString:`?

Comment: @iOSDev The whole array as a string. Preferably divided by commas after each value.

Comment: It's "objectForKey", not "valueForKeyPath". valueForKeyPath can lead to surprising results.

Comment: You say you "need" to get the values into an NSString. They are two independent values. Putting them into one NSString seems unlikely to be the right thing to do. Especially if these are tags that might not be displayed but examined by some code, most likely you want to keep them as an array,

Comment: @gnasher729 I just needed to display the values in a label separated by commas. Nothing more than that. Did you downvote the question? If so care to explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSArray *array =[data valueForKeyPath:@"tags"];

NSString *requiredString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. Is it possible to separate each value by a comma?

Comment: Yes.. very much.. just change @" " to @"," in the above code.